# How to return ActiveRecord Association Proxy on ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

so I have a standard has_many through association in my models, very similar to the question here: [Loop through ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy with each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116091/loop-through-activerecordassociationscollectionproxy-with-each)

I used the advice in that problem but I think I am having some trouble getting it through on my ERB file so that it shows up in my app. At the moment I have the following:

```
<%= @memberships.map do |a| %>
<%=a.name%>
<% end %>
```

In this scenario, the membership model is the one through which users and organizations have many though (@memberships = @user.organizations). So the @memberships.class returns

`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Organization`

on the rails console. So the moment, in the browser the code returns on a page where the user is in two orgs:

```
orgone orgtwo["\n", "\n"]
```

I just don't know how to manipulate the proxy classes to return what I want. Thanks!

UPDATE:

I figured it out, I had to remove the = at the top of the block, and I added some styling with a comma:

```
<% @memberships.map do |a| %>
<h3><%=a.name %> <%= ", " unless a == @memberships.last %></h3>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What DO you want? Print the name of each membership? @memberships.each should work fine.

Comment: yes, I have figured out how to print memberships when there is only one, but not when there is multiple, @memberships.each gave me, #<Enumerator:0x007fdfaa07dc58> in the browser.

Comment: The way to do that is actually `<%= memberships.map(&:name).to_sentence %>` which will give you "one and two" or "one,two, and three"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print the name of each membership, what you want is

```
<% @memberships.each do |membership| %>
   <%= membership.name %>
<% end -%>
```

The `<%` prefix in ERB executes code without appending the results to the output buffer, while the `<%=` prefix outputs the string representation of the result of the expression.  Since each returns an enumerator, a `<%=` will return the string representation of the enumerator which is something like `#<Enumerator:0xDEADBEEF`.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! I figured it out a little earlier, very dumb mistake on my part, just got back on stack and showing the +1 love. Thanks though!